# Usage of mongoose deep-populate unclear

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I would like to use the deep-populate plugin for mongoose queries. Most certainly I am to unexperienced but, I don't success to deep-populate something.
Here's my scheme:

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var MMAnswersSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  user: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
  item: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'MMItem'},
  answer: [
    {
      skalaAnswer: Number,
      freitextAnswer: String,
      multipleChoiceAnswer: String,
      answered_at: { type: Date, required: true, default: Date.now }
    }
  ],
  last_answered: { type: Date, required: true, default: Date.now }
});

MMAnswersSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
  this.last_answered = Date.now;

  next();
});

mongoose.model('MMAnswer', MMAnswersSchema);

var deepPopulate = require('mongoose-deep-populate')(mongoose);
MMAnswersSchema.plugin(deepPopulate);
```

Did I put the deepPopulate require stuff at the right place?

I use this route now to get my stuff:

```js
// Alle Antworten des aktuellen Users laden
    // Verwendet von der Historie
    .get('/mm-answers/:user_id/get-all-answers', function (req, res, next) {
        Answer.find({user:req.params.user_id}, function (err, answer) {
            if(err){
                return next(err);
            }
            res.json(answer);
        })
            .deepPopulate('item')

    })
```

I want that it replaces the id with the actual item and the item itself contains a 'ofBox'-field which I also want to be replaced with the actual box document (thats why I use deep-populate). 
Using the query above simply doesn't give me any result. I still have the ID in the item field.
If I run the standard .populate('item') command, it replaces the item ID with the item itself but unfortunately not the ofBox ID inside the item. (thats why I need deep-populate).

Can someone help me to figure it out? I guess I made a mistake in importing/ registrating the plugin correctly...-.-

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the `deepPopulate` call before you execute the query, something like this:

```js
    // Alle Antworten des aktuellen Users laden
    // Verwendet von der Historie
    .get('/mm-answers/:user_id/get-all-answers', function (req, res, next) {
        Answer.find({ user: req.params.user_id }).deepPopulate('item').exec(function (err, answer) {
            if (err) {
                return next(err);
            }

            res.json(answer);
        });
    });
```

Comment: TypeError: router.post(...).get(...).get(...).get(...).get(...).get(...).put(...).put(...).post(...).get(...).get(...).post(...).post(...).get(...).get(...).get(...).get(...).get(...).get(...).put(...).put(...).put(...).put(...).put(...).put(...).put(...).put(...).get(...).get(...).get(...).post(...).get(...).post(...).put(...).put(...).get(...).get(...).post(...).get(...).put(...).post(...).put(...).put(...).put(...).get(...).get(...).get(...).deepPopulate is not a function

Comment: @chakuze: In the first code snippet I sent you, I accidentally put it after the `.get` method, I edited the example. Could you try the code as it looks now?

Answer (score 0):

In the model you just need to add the fields you wanna populate when you add the plugin:

```
 const mongoose = require('mongoose');
 const deepPopulate = require('mongoose-deep-populate')(mongoose);

    const MMAnswersSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
      user: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
      item: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'MMItem'},
      answer: [
        {
          skalaAnswer: Number,
          freitextAnswer: String,
          multipleChoiceAnswer: String,
          answered_at: { type: Date, required: true, default: Date.now }
        }
      ],
      last_answered: { type: Date, required: true, default: Date.now }
    });

    MMAnswersSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
      this.last_answered = Date.now;

      next();
    });



    MMAnswersSchema.plugin(deepPopulate, {
    populate: {
        user: {
            select:'_id name lastName'
        },
        item: {
            select:'_id name'
        },

        });
    const MMAnswers = mongoose.model('answers',MMAnswersSchema);
    module.exports = { MMAnswers };
```

Finally when you need to use the deep population JUST add whatever field you wanna populate

```
await MMAnswers.findOne({your search}).deepPopulate('user').exec();
```

or

```
await MMAnswers.findOne({your search}).deepPopulate('user item').exec();
```